# jQuery function(event) event.target.id is blank when clicking linked text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a side menu that when clicked slides out to reveal a content panel. Based on the menu item clicked I obviously need different stuff to populate in the panel.

I wrote a function to operate the menu/panel and it partially works. However, I am trying to determine what to load based on `event.target.id` (as the function takes `event`) but it only has a value when I click very close to the edges of the linked square. When I click near the actual text which are `h1` and `h6` and have no `id`'s it doesn't work.

Live demo (click near the edges of the 'Styles' square and then in the middle): http://jsfiddle.net/mANuD/

```
<div id="application-frame">
  <div class="panel"></div>
  <ul id="slide-out-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="item" id="styles-menu">
        <h1>S</h1>
        <h6>Styles</h6>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="item" id="designers-menu">
        <h1>D</h1>
        <h6>Designers</h6>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="item" id="code-menu">
        <h1>C</h1>
        <h6>Code</h6>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="item" id="help-menu">
        <h1>?</h1>
        <h6>Help</h6>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I fix/improve this so that it doesn't matter where in the linked area I click?

Comment: Always include the relevant markup and code **inthe question itself**, don't just link (not even to jsfiddle, although that's a nice plus). Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: just change `e.target.id` to `this.id` to work with the ID of the bound element and not the target.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change `event.target.id` to `event.currentTarget.id` or `this.id`.

The `event.target` is always the deepest element clicked, while `event.currentTarget` or `this` will point to the element to which the handler is bound, or to the element that the delegate selector matched.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there's a border or padding on some of the descendant elements, and so `event.target` is a descendant of the element on which the handler is (effectively) hooked up.

Two options:

1. Use `this.id` to get the `id` of the element the handler was (effectively) bound to. This usually does what you want. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mANuD/1/)
2. I don't think you need it in this situation, but the other handy tool in the toolkit for this is `closest`, which finds the first element matching a selector by looking at the element you give it, then its parent, then *its* parent, etc. So for instance, `$(this).closest(".item").attr("id")` or `$(event.target).closest(".item").attr("id")` (since the items you want have class `item`). [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mANuD/2/) But again, I believe #1 is what you want in this case.