# event.target.id VS event.currentTarget.id VS this.id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this sample code provided below:

HTML:

```
<button id = '33' class = "clickme">Click here</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click",".clickme",function(event){ 
    var eti = event.target.id;
    var eci = event.currentTarget.id;
    var ti = this.id;

    alert ("1: " + eti + "   2: " + eci + "   3: " + ti);
}
```

These 3 events, alerts the same value and I thought it also plays the same role but not in this link I found in SO: [jquery function(event) event.target.id is blank when clicking linked text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700452/jquery-functionevent-event-target-id-is-blank-when-clicking-linked-text).

**Now my question is:**

**1.)** What is the *difference* between using: `event.target.id`, `event.currentTarget.id` and `this.id`?

**2.)** When should I *use* `event.target.id`, `event.currentTarget.id` and `this.id`?

**3.)** And which works better among these three?

Does anybody have an idea and explanation why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this example

```
<div id="maindiv" onclick="callback(event, this);">
  <span id="span" onclick="callback(event, this);"> SPan</span>
  <p id="p" onclick="callback(event, this);">This is p </p>
</div>

function callback(e, thisObj) {
       console.log('this = ', thisObj.id);
       console.log('target = ', e.target.id);
       console.log('currentTarget = ', e.currentTarget.id);
    }
```

event.target is what dispatches the event.
ex: if you click on `p` `event.target` will be `p` but `event.currentTarget` will be `p` when `callback` of `p` will be called `event.currentTarget` will be `maindiv` when `callback` will be called cause of event bubbling.

```
`this` refers to `event.currentTarget`
```

See this one for details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets

Here is a same question i think see this one
[Difference between e.target and e.currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget)

Comment: Ahh, that's why... Thankss

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.id` and `this.id` are the same, in the first one you are accessing the target from the event object in the second you are accessing it through jquery object.

`event.currentTarget.id`

> The current DOM element within the event bubbling phase.

As per it's [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

In JavaScript, events [bubble](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/). This means that an event propagates through the ancestors of the element the event fired on.

You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g83o2hrr/1/) and check various event properties.

Comment: It is more helpful if you answer the question (at least in brief) than sending the reader to links (that might get outdated as time goes on)