# event.currentTarget getting undefined on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to get the attribute value of the element clicked in my javascript code but for some reason the value I am getting is undefined.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<c:button buttonLabel="Skype" buttonClass="valmetSecondaryButton noMargin" id="I_WANT_THIS_VALUE" onclick="{!c.openSkype}"/>
```

JS:

```
console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
```

This is working on Internet Explorer, havent tested in Firefox, but not working in Chrome. Also just so you know I am using Lightening Component, Salesforce!

Comment: Something like this asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456290/event-target-id-vs-event-currenttarget-id-vs-this-id Thanks

Comment: @kapilyadav i tried that link, no success, could you show me with a code or smth how do I get fixed this, I understood that in my case i am applying event bubbling but I dont know how can I make such that when the button is clicked stop it there and return id attribute of this button!

Answer (score 2):

Although not directly related to `salesforce-lightning` as your question is tagged, this thread is the first result when searching for `evt currentTarget undefined` so i'll leave my general answer here:

I've encountered a weird issue where `event.currentTarget` was `undefined` when it definitely shouldn't be - and it even appeared to be defined at the start of the event handler, but just disappear later.

It turns out that `evt.currentTarget` may disappear from the event when execution is passed on from the event - for example when `await`ing a network request or trying to access the event from a setTimeout.

From MDN docs:

> Note: The value of event.currentTarget is only available while the event is being handled. If you console.log() the event object, storing it in a variable, and then look for the currentTarget key in the console, its value will be null.

This can also be demonstrated with the following code at the top of the event handler:

```js
console.log(e.currentTarget);
setTimeout(()=> console.log(e.currentTarget), 0);
```

If you want to run some async actions before using `event.currentTarget`, you can probably just save the value of `event.currentTarget` into a variable before the async actions, and then later use the variable.

```js
let elem = event.currentTarget;
await doSomethingAsync();
console.log(elem);
```

Comment: Any idea for a workaround? I need to set `event.currentTarget=null` after performing some functions with `await` but it disappears.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov You should be able to simply save `event.currentTarget` into a variable before the `await`s, and then later use the element you saved in the variable

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
<span id="{!v.teamMember.email}" onclick="{!c.openSkype}">
                        <c:button buttonLabel="Skype" buttonClass="valmetSecondaryButton noMargin"/>
</span>
```

Thanks you all for your interest on solving this!

This link helped me solve the problem: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160830/lighting-component-get-html-button-id-in-controller-js-working-in-firefox-not

Event Bubbling